# Is there a proper use of the article "the" in broadcasting?

Tags: articles

Meteorologists say, "on average" vs "on the average," when referencing weather data; why?

Comment: I think this would benefit from a few full sentence examples.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22on+average%22).

Comment: Because it has become a fixed expression.

Answer (score 2):

"On average" is [a commonly used phrase meaning that something is generally or typically true.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-average#:%7E:text=If%20you%20say%20that%20something,More%20Synonyms%20of%20on%20average)

> On average, American firms remain the most productive in the world.

It is also used for literal mathematical average calculations:

> On average the temperature in December is 12 degrees

> On average a ten-year old gets an hour of homework a night

*(Note that in the above cases the statement may or may not be referring to a literal average calculation.)*

Collins lists "On the average" as a British English alternative, but I hear "on average" much more frequently.

You might hear "the average" more often in meteorology:

> The average temperature in December is 12 degrees.